# Privacy printing in Mac

Tags: network, macos, printing

Does anybody know how to prevent filename and username to be revealed when printing to a network printer?
I would like to hide that information by default, specially the filename since it might reveal a lot of information. (Im using Yosemite although I doubt that matters at all)

Comment: rename the file before printing

Comment: I wanted something professional for everything I print...

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can setup header and footer in the page setup or print setup *(depend on which program you print from)*, so that the file name isn't shown.

If your network printer support "secure print" then use this feature, because then it will only be you that'll see the printed.

Comment: Its not that. Thanks for the try, but its the filename itself. Not shown on the printed document but only on the printer's logs.